# AngularJS: How to display an element on another div when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an array of letters and I want to log whatever letter is clicked.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-10 col-lg-1 letters" 
ng-repeat="choice in images[num].letters track by $index">
    <ul>
        <li ng-click="displayLetter()"class="wordList">
            {{choice}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.displayLetter = function() {
    console.log($scope.choice);
};
```

letters is stored inside an array of chars assigned to an object. The object is in an array of objects.

```
$scope.images = 
    [ 
    { pics: ["img/carrion.png", "img/telefrag.png", "img/thunder-skull.png", "img/skull-ring.png"], word: 'skull', length: 5, 
    letters: ['u', randLet(), randLet(), randLet(), 's', randLet(), 'k', 'l', randLet(), randLet(), randLet(), 'l' ]}
```

I keep getting undefined. How do I solve this?

I even tried adding an ng-model

```
      <li ng-model="choice" ng-click="displayLetter()" class="wordList">
            {{choice}}
        </li>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `$scope` is for the controller itself not for every single item in `ng-repeat`. Try it like this

```html
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-10 col-lg-1 letters">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="choice in images[num].letters track by $index" ng-click="displayLetter(choice)" class="wordList">
        {{choice}}
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
$scope.displayLetter = function(choice) {
    console.log(choice);
};
```

And as Lex mentioned below if you want each choice to be an `li` then the `ng-repeat` should on `li`. If you `4` elements in array and have the `ng-repeat` in the `div` you would get `4` `div` instead of `4` `li`.

Comment: One other issue is that the `ng-repeat` should be on the `<li>`, otherwise a new `<div>` and `<ul>` will be created for each item in the collection which is likely not the desired output.

Comment: I forgot to notice that. Thanks @lex. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I quite understand your question.

But you could do the following:

*file.js*

```
    var app = angular.module('test', []);

    app.controller('maincontroller', function($scope) {


      $scope.displayLetter = function(clicked) {
        console.log(clicked);
      };

      $scope.images = [{ 
        "pics": [
          "http://www.aviacaobr.com.br/wp/img.png", 
          "http://www.psf.gov.pk/images/icons/gallery.png", 
          "http://handicrafts.nic.in/dc_hc_photo_gallery.png"
        ], 
        "word": 'skull', 
        "length": 5, 
        "letters": [
          'u', 
          randLet(), 
          randLet(), 
          randLet(), 
          's', 
          randLet(), 
          'k', 
          'l', 
          randLet(), 
          randLet(), 
          randLet(), 
          'l'
        ]
      }];

      function randLet(){
        return 'a';
      }

    });
```

*file.html*

```
    <li><body ng-controller="maincontroller">

    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-10 col-lg-1 letters" 
  ng-repeat="choice in images[0].letters ">
      <ul>
          <li ng-click="displayLetter(choice)" class="wordList">
              {{choice}}
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

The function *displayLetter* receive a parameter, that is the clicked item.
And in *ng-repeat*, when *ng-click* call *displayLetter* pass the clicked item.

See in Plunker: [Click Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/aGAjZXIiYW5J7ZpyCyvG)